# LDAP Server is not available

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I am using LDAP for User Authentication in MVC.My code goes below as follows:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            bool validation;
                try
                {   
                    LdapConnection ldc = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier((string)null, false, false));
                    NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(model.UserName, model.Password, "XXXXXXX");
                    ldc.Credential = nc;
                    ldc.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
                    ldc.Bind(nc); // user has authenticated at this point, as the credentials were used to login to the dc.
                    validation = true;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

                    //validation = true;
                }
                catch (LdapException)
                {
                    validation = false;
                }
                return View(model);
}
```

but i am getting an error as "LDAP server not available"

**Web.Config:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
              <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="10"/>
 </authentication>  
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
              attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"  />

      </providers>
</membership>
 <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://XXXXXXX:389/DC=XXXX,DC=XXXX" />
```

Comment: Can you connect to the LDAP server using any standard AD tools?

Comment: I dont know about this can u give me any snippest for this?

Comment: Try using Directory Entry[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C] or LDAPSoft[http://www.ldapsoft.com/connectingtoactivedirectoryremotely.html]

Comment: As I am very new to this concept..can u provide me some link or tutorials on this which gives me the idea about the user authentication using LDAP speacially in MVC

Answer (score 1):

You did not set the path to the LDAP server (currently it is null)

```
LdapConnection ldc = new LdapConnection(
      new LdapDirectoryIdentifier((string)null, false, false)
);
```

To debug, get rid of try..catch and see where exactly the error comes from. You might need to verify the path with your network administrator or use any tool like [LDAP Browser](http://www.ldapadministrator.com/download.htm) where you could see if path and credentials would work.

Also, make sure that the way you want to authenticate is correct. If this is an intranet application then it might be that you could setup integrated Windows authentication which will not require any custom login process and can be configured on IIS.

Comment: Actullay I dont know the process to Authenticate the User using LDAP and I am very confused about this.Do u have any basic Idea about this and can u provide some example code for this

Comment: Again, you get "LDAP server not available" because you did not specified the server.

Comment: The web.config file you have, has nothing to do with the code in your method. If you look at the code you create a new LdapConnection but where is the server name? You set NULL instead of path to the server. Read more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms257181(v=vs.80).aspx